# How to plot a pie chart from an object dataframe column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot a column information as a pie chart. How to make it?

```
redemption_type = redemptions['redemption_type']
redemption_type.describe()
```

```
count     641493
unique        12
top       MPPAID
freq      637145
Name: redemption_type, dtype: object
```

This pie chart should consist of 12 different values with their frequency.

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the easiest way

```
redemptions['redemption_type'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
```

Here is one with `plotly-express`

```py
    temp = pd.DataFrame(redemptions['redemption_type'].value_counts())
    temp.index.name = 'val'
    temp.columns = ['count']
    temp = temp.reset_index()
    temp

    fig = px.pie(temp, names='val', values='count')
    # fig.update_traces(textinfo='value') # uncomment this line if you want actual value on the chart instead of %
    fig.show()
```

Comment: The plotly-express way is exactly what I need with all necessary info, Thank you!